# SplitView with tabBar in its detailView

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, ipad

I have created a Split view.Now I want to add Tab bar in my detail view.
Is it possible.Please let me know if you have any sample code/program

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit UITabBarController which will be shown as second view in your split view. By the way this is bad practice to use tabBarController nested in some part of your screen.

in your .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTabBarController : UITabBarController

@end
```

in .m file

```
#import "MyTabBarController.h"
@implementation MyTabBarController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FirstViewController *fVC = [[[FirstViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; //Here you create instances of your view controllers. You even can create UINavigationController instances linked to those viewControllers and put them in array instead of ViewControllers
    fVC.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fVC.png"];//Here you set up UITabBarController item image
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:fVC, nil];// Here you put your view controllers in NSMutableArray for UITabBarController
    [self setViewControllers:controllers animated:NO]; //ta-daa. You assign array of view controllers to UITabBarController and create sections for them.
}
```

This is structure of UITabBarController:
[image: UITabBarController structure]
for more see this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: thanks but when i push tabbar in my detailView navigation the back button comes in the detail view instead of Master popover button. i cannot access that i have to go back first for that

Comment: You shouldn't push to tabBarController. You just need no nest it's view to your splitView. You can create this controller's instance and set frame according to the size of your superview.